# Is it advisable to share the link of the entire project on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, asking-questions, third-party

I would like someone to review a small PHP project of mine - the entire source code of which has been uploaded on Github.

Is it advisable to share the link of the entire project here on Code Review?

Comment: We require the code to be reviewed to be part of the question itself on Code Review, for many reasons. Please see the other meta question this has been marked as duplicate of. If you can't fit the code into the question, then post duplicate questions *in an organized way*

Comment: Thanks Simon. I went through the other question and I understand the point. I will try and see if I can fit the code into the post itself without making the post too long.